# JavaScript works fine when pasted in to console, not as bookmark

Tags: javascript

There are a few lines of JavaScript that work when pasted in to the console but not when I put the same code into a bookmark with javascript: prefix.

For example,

```
document.getElementById("id").selectedIndex = "0" // select
document.getElementById("id2").value = "Text" // textarea
```

But if I create a bookmark with,

```
javascript:document.getElementById("id").value = "Text"
```

What ends up happening when I click the bookmark while on the appropriate page is a white page appears with only "Text" on it. Likewise with selectedIndex, "0" appears on the page.

I've made a workaround where I use prompt and the default text contains the JavaScript for easy pasting into the console, but it is far from ideal.

I've also Googled around but haven't been able to find anything.

Thanks

Comment: What browser and version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent your page from navigating to a white page with "Text" on the page, use the void operator:

```
javascript:void(document.getElementById("id").value = "Text")
```

`void` lets the code evaluate to `undefined`, instead of returning the value you assigned to "id". This would also prevent page navigation.